# Reflection retrieve values of getter without explicitily coding

Tags: java

I need to iterate through a list and within that list object there can be lists. it is nested inside one and one. so i need to get all the lists objects and validate. so i use reflection. but i cannot get the relevant data of the object while looping. can i do that.

```
    if (valueToValidate instanceof Collection<?>) {
        // valueToValidate is a collection
        Collection<?> col = (Collection<?>) valueToValidate;
        for (Object object : col) {
            List<ConstraintViolation> constraintViolation = validator
                    .validate(object);
            addViolations(violationMessages, constraintViolation);

            try {
                Class<?> c = object.getClass();

                Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
                for (Method method : methods) {

                    if (isGetter(method)) {
                        if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(method
                                .getReturnType())) {
                            validateList(validatedObject, method, null,
                                    validator, violationMessages);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

my code is somethin like above. i need to get the object.getOptionsList(); something like that without hard coding the 'getOptionsList()'. that can be any list. Please help me on this. I stucked on this

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: There is no error but i cannot fulfill my needful